# Scala type inference and multiple arguments list

Tags: scala, type-inference, typechecking

(Scala 2.11.8)

Consider the following code:

```
trait Class[A] {
  def f1[B >: A](arg1: Int)(ord: Ordering[B]): Int

  def f2[B >: A](arg1: Int, ord: Ordering[B]): Int

  def f[B >: A](ord: Ordering[B]): Int = {
    f1(123)(ord) // Compilation error!
    f2(123, ord) // OK
  }
}
```

Here, line `f1(123)(ord)` raises `type mismatch; found : Ordering[B] required: Ordering[A] Note: B >: A, but trait Ordering is invariant in type T. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as _ >: A. (SLS 3.2.10)`

If we change the call to `f1[B](123)(ord)`, error disappears.

Why does the presence of multiple arguments list confuses the typechecker? Is this a bug, or an expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug - the separation into parameter lists means that the type parameter is inferred based on the *first* argument list alone:

```
f1(123)(ord)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
val partiallyApplied = f1(123)
partiallyApplied(ord)
```

Now - what is `partiallyApplied`'s type? Since the type parameter wasn't explicitly set, and there's no argument / return type to use for inference, the type parametter is inferred to be `A` (there's no specific `B` yet! So `partiallyApplied`'s type is `(Ordering[A]) => Int`), hence using it with `Ordering[B]` later gives the exception.

In contrast, when calling:

```
f2(123, ord)
```

Since `ord` has type `Ordering[B]`, the type parameter can be inferred to be `B`, hence compilation succeeds.