# Generic nested type inference works with arity-2 but not with currying

Tags: scala, generics, currying

Trying to figure out why the code compiles for nested type inference on method with arity-2 but not with currying.

```scala
object Test
{
    trait Version
    object VersionOne extends Version

    trait Request[A <: Version]
    trait RequestOne extends Request[VersionOne.type]

    case class HelloWorld() extends RequestOne

    def test1[A <: Version, T <: Request[A]](t : T, a : A): T = t
    def test2[A <: Version, T <: Request[A]](t : T)(a : A): T = t
}

// This works
Test.test1(Test.HelloWorld(), Test.VersionOne)

// This doesn't
Test.test2(Test.HelloWorld())(Test.VersionOne)
```

test2 fails to compile with the following error:

> Error:(22, 73) inferred type arguments [Nothing,A$A96.this.Test.HelloWorld] do not conform to method test2's type parameter bounds [A <: A$A96.this.Test.Version,T <: A$A96.this.Test.Request[A]]
>   def get$$instance$$res1 = /* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ Test.test2(Test.HelloWorld())(Test.VersionOne)

Looking forward to some insights on the same.

Comment: you may also interested in scala puzzler explaining this problem http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DmytroMitin already explained why it does fail.

However, you can solve the problem this way, using the [**Partially-Applied Type**](https://typelevel.org/cats/guidelines.html) trick, together with [**Generalized Type Constraints**](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html).

```
def test2[T](t: T): Test2PartiallyApplied[T] = new Test2PartiallyApplied(t)

final class Test2PartiallyApplied[T](private val t: T) extends AnyVal {
  def apply[A <: Version](a: A)(implicit ev: T <:< Request[A]): T = t
}
```

Which you can use like this.

```
Test.test2(Test.HelloWorld())(Test.VersionOne)
// res: HelloWorld = HelloWorld()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Nothing` in compile error usually means that some type parameters were not inferred.

Try to specify them explicitly

```
Test.test2[Test.VersionOne.type, Test.RequestOne](Test.HelloWorld())(Test.VersionOne)
```

Difference between `test1` and `test2` is not only in currying. For example, generally in `test2(t: ...)(a: ...)` type of `a` can depend on value of `t`. So for `test2` type inferrence is more complicated than for `test1`.

[Scala type inference and multiple arguments list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175614/scala-type-inference-and-multiple-arguments-list)

[Type inference with type aliases and multiple parameter list function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635297/type-inference-with-type-aliases-and-multiple-parameter-list-function)

[Multiple parameter closure argument type not inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118264/multiple-parameter-closure-argument-type-not-inferred)

[What's the difference between multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803211/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Hi Dmytro, thank you for your answer. I was looking for a way wherein I won’t have to specific the type parameters explicitly, do you think there’s a way to achieve that?