# Scala composition of generic types

Tags: scala, generics

I have a complex use case of generics type which has been simplified below

```
trait A
class AB extends A{
  val v = 10
}

trait X[T<:A]{
  def request: T
}

class XY extends X[AB]{
  def request = new AB()
}
class Test extends App{

  /**
    * X[A]
    * X[AB]
    * XY[A]
    * XY[AB]
    */
  def test[C<:A, D <: X[C]](t:Int)(input: D): Unit ={
    print(input.getClass.getName)
  }
  implicit val req = new XY()
  test(2)(req)

}
```

test method should support the Type scenarios defined in comment section. I'm getting the below compilation error.

```
Error:(33, 7) inferred type arguments [XY] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [D <: X[Nothing]] test(2)(req)
```

Is this syntactically legal? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless it's a part of simplification, if `D` is used in signature only once it can be removed: `test[C<:A](t:Int)(input: X[C])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can't infer the type of `C` in 2 steps with a definition like this.

So either have the compiler do it in 1 step, by having both `D` and `C` in the definition of the `input` argument:

```
def test[C <: A, D <: X[C]](t: Int)(input: D with X[C]): Unit
```

Or have an implicit evidence for `D <: X[C]`, that will help the compiler to infer `C` in 2 steps:

```
def test[C <: A, D <: X[_]](t: Int)(input: D)(implicit ev: D <:< X[C]): Unit
```

Answer (score 2):

`Nothing` in compile error usually means that some type wasn't inferred.

Try to specify type parameters explicitly

```
test[AB, XY](2)(req)
```

[Generic nested type inference works with arity-2 but not with currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585312/generic-nested-type-inference-works-with-arity-2-but-not-with-currying)